# How to link the internal Component with the footer text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have to link the Privacy Component with my footer's "Privacy and Policy" text i tried to connect it with anchor tag but its not working and on the path it is showig 404 Page is not found how can i connect that ?

```
import Image from "next/image";
import Privact from "./PrivacyComponent"
import PrivacyComponent from "./PrivacyComponent";
export default function Footer() {
  return (
    <>
      {/* Footer Section: With Links Info Newsletter */}
     
              <nav className="flex flex-col space-y-3">
                <a
                  href="#/PrivacyComponent"
                  className="font-medium text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-500"
                >
                  Privacy and Policy
                </a>
               
            
               
              </nav>
```

I just want to connect the external Privacy component with my footer's privacy text when i click on it, it will jump to https://localhost:3000.com/PrivacyComponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show like that you have to use PrivacyComponent as page like `privacy`. after that you can import you `PrivacyComponent` in `privacy` page.

```
<Link href="/PrivacyComponent">
       PrivacyComponent
</Link>
```